# How to build a simple dataset for Microsoft Power BI?

Tags: dictionary, mapping, metadata, powerbi

I'm tasked with creating a map that allows me to plot points on a map and attach metadata to those points. To give some context, I work for a NFP care provider, we want to see where our clients are based, the complexity of the support they require. On top of this we want to plot where our staff are so that we can then divide up the work load fairly for them.

This is all completely new to me. I have tried a demo of e-spatial and it's a lot easier to use, but very expensive for what will probably amount to a one off exercise, which is why Power BI is appealing.

I have created a dataset and refined it but I'm not sure I've done the best possible job, these are the fields I've used:

- House/Staff/Client name
- Type
- Country
- Suburb
- Postal code
- Address
- No. residents
- Low Complexity
- Medium complexity
- High complexity

The data is pretty 'clean' but I could really do with some examples of how to build a simple dataset, I can't seem to find any, anywhere. Are they considered IP?

Comment: If "complexity" were a single field, (1=low, 2=medium, 3=high) then could you color code a map point using that field?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Guy's comment.  Would be better to have Complexity be a single column.

We have some useful help topics you might review here:
https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/685803-tips-and-tricks-for-power-bi-map-visualizations
https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/556194-tutorial-filled-maps-choropleths-in-power-bi

Comment: Thanks both. I have added the extra column as suggested. What I've found is that it's good to have both low, medium & high as separate columns as well as having the áll in one'column as you've suggested, the reason is this:

The all in one column means I can create a 'complexity type' slicer (very handy) but having them separately means that I can create a 'complexity breakdown' pie chart, so both are useful.

Have I missed something; is it possible to create both from just the single column that includes all complexity types?

Comment: You should be able to create a pie chart by with just a single column for Complexity. Your data set should have a column that's unique across rows if you'd like to do a count (count distinct).